# (AS7) Error calling remote EJB method with proxified CDI bean in parameter

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, cdi, ejb-3.1, proxy-classes

Can I call a remote EJB method with CDI bean in parameter method?

Like this:

I have a **LoggedUserProducer.java** thats produces a User from the database.

```
public class LoggedUserProducer {

    @Produces
    @SessionScoped
    @LoggedUser
    public User produceLoggedUser() throws Exception {
        ... //load user from database with a request token
        return user;
    }
}
```

And I have a JSF Bean thats make the EJB call:

**CarController.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CarController implements Serializable {

    @Inject //I have a producer to create the EJB proxy
    private RepairRemote repairRemote; //My remote EJB

    @Inject
    @LoggedUser
    private User loggedUser; //my User produced by LoggedUserProducer

    private Car car;

    public void repairCar() throws Exception {
        ... //some actions...

        Repair repair = new Repair(this.car)
        repair.setPerformedBy(loggedUser); //setting my proxified cdi bean into a POJO

        repairRemote.repair(repair); //here throws ClassNotFoundException;
    }
```

and the Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ClassNotFoundException marshaling EJB parameters

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:229)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:216)
    ...
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
at org.jboss.weld.proxies.RepairRemote$-248248579$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.repair(RepairRemote$-248248579$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.mycompany.services.controller.CarController.repairCar(CarController.java:118)
at com.mycompany.services.controller.CarController$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.repairCar(CarController$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
...
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.portalcarweb.client.model.User$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy from [Module "deployment.portalcarweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I don't know why my remote EJB can't find the class **com.mycompany.portalcarweb.client.model.User$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy**

My **User.java** is deployed in a JBoss 7 module.
My EJB client and server have the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder and declaring the correct module to access this class.

Thanks (sorry my english).

*update*

My two webapps are packaged in WARs file.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSF bean isn't being managed by CDI (@ViewScoped is JSF only), unless you're using something like Seam 3, CODI or wrote your own new @ViewScoped.

Edit: Actually, it probably isn't a bug. You'll have to pass a copy, any time you're dealing with remote EJBs copies are the best way to go.

Comment: I already use Seam 3. But I don't this error is related to JSF or Seam. Because it's only EJB call sending a cdi bean (produced by a cdi `@Producer`)

Comment: Which version of JBoss AS are you using?

Comment: This seems like a bug, try a newer version and see if it's fixed.

Comment: I tried with 7.1.3 (built by sources) and EAP 6.1.0.Beta.. and still getting error

Comment: I've added an Edit to the answer, you need to use copies of the objects instead of the actual CDI bean.